# How to target specific part of the_content()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the text editor in WordPress only to store the title and the description of the sections on my website. For now, everything is in the PHP file, so the text editor is blank. I'm trying to write down 5 `<h1>` tags within `<p>` tags and then call the first pair on the first section, second on the second one and so on. Is that even possible, because I could not find a way how to do it yet?

Comment: you'll need to  use shortcodes

Comment: How to make a shortcode that take the content from the h1 tag for example?

Comment: Hi  Vladimir-Manov
You can use **Advanced Custom Fields** for this. There is option for repeated fields. You can use that field to add multiple data.
Even there are any other option provided by this plugin.
All value for that fields added in **Postmeta** table. you can easily retrieve the data.